# How to use CASE here?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table having 6 columns(A,B,C,D,E,F). If a fixed column, lets say D is not null, I want to fetch 3 columns D,E,F;  else if D is null I want to fetch other 3 columns A,B,C.

Am trying to use this but not able to proceed.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL 
    THEN SELECT D, E, F
    ELSE
    SELECT A,B,C 
     END
FROM Mytable.
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the check in each column:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL THEN D ELSE A END, 
   CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL THEN E ELSE B END,
   CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL THEN F ELSE C END
FROM Mytable
```

or use a `UNION`

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM Mytable
WHERE D IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT D,E,F
FROM Mytable
WHERE D IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN D IS NULL THEN A ELSE D END as C1,
   CASE WHEN D IS NULL THEN B ELSE E END as C2,
   CASE WHEN D IS NULL THEN C ELSE F END as C3
FROM tbl
```